# Why I can't get a precise positioning by using GeoCoordinateWatcher?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm developing a wp8 app, in which I want to show my device's position in Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.Map.

The current problem is that I can't get a precise positioning by using GeoCoordinateWatcher, it always have a deviation around about 500 meters (BTW, I'm in China).

Could you give me some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the desired accuracy to High:

```
var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the reason, this is because the map data is used by Chinese government's Mars coordinates, but the position what I got is used by earth coordinate system, and they have a deviation.